# Problem with IE8 session sharing?

Tags: session, internet-explorer-8, sharing, loose-coupling

Hello how do i handle session sharing in IE8 in java?? I have an application where multiple users can login. Before in IE7 we dint have this sort of problem. But since its loosely coupled in IE8, how do we avoid this in java?

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs elaboration before it can be answered.

The most likely answer is "Choose 'New Session' from the File Menu".

Start by reading http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/04/05/understanding-browser-session-lifetime.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/05/06/session-cookies-sessionstorage-and-ie8.aspx.